# how do I group by by hour in postgresql with a "time" field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column `ctime` of type `time without time zone`.

```
  |   cdate    |  ctime   
  +------------+----------
  | 2016-12-24 | 12:02:17
  | 2016-12-24 | 12:02:32
  | 2016-12-24 | 12:03:00
  | 2016-12-24 | 12:02:10
```

I would like to group by both `cdate` and `ctime` but would like for `ctime` to count only hours.

Comment: You can probably do `group by cdate, hour(ctime)`.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @jarlh: I tried that, but it's telling me there's no "hour" function `group by cdate, hour(ctime)` gives me `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: `extract(hour from ctime)` is the ANSI SQL way to get the hour part. Perhaps works bettter?

Comment: @jarlh: there is no `hour()` function in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks. (I wasn't sure about that, that's why I added "probably"...) How about `EXTRACT`?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

use `date_trunc`:

`group by cdate, date_trunc('hour', ctime)`

Answer (score 44):

I think `date_part('hour', ctime)` is a better choice if you just want to group based on the hour.

```
date_part('hour', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40')    ---> 20
date_trunc('hour', interval '2 days 3 hours 40 minutes')    ---> 2 days 03:00:00
```

Comment: The major difference, which should be highlighted in this answer, is that `date_part('hour', ctime)` will not differentiate between 4:20 today and 4:20 yesterday (yielding `4` for both), whereas `date_trunc('hour', ctime)` will (yielding the full original timestamp just with units smaller than an hour truncated away).