# Can I reduce the number of SQL queries here (Postgresql)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

It's been a while since I've touched SQL. 
I'm working on a pretty large database. 
In a certain table which has some 30 million rows I'm trying to figure out when the highest number of entries was made for a certain period e.g. a year, down to the detail-level of one hour.

What I do now is something like this:
For the year 2018:

Find month with highest entry number for 2018 (i.e. 12 queries):

```
select count(*) from sing
where to_char(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') like '2018-01-%'

select count(*) from sing
where to_char(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') like '2018-02-%'
```

After I find the month with the highest number I must find the day (i.e. up to 31 queries) :

```
select count(*) from sing
where to_char(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2018-01-01'

select count(*) from sing
where to_char(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2018-01-02'
```

After I find the day with the highest number I must find the hour (i.e. 24 queries):

```
    select count(*) from sing
        where to_char(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '2018-01-02 08:00:00' 
and to_char(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= '2018-01-02 08:59:59'
```

As you can see this is a tedious task. So my question is, if and how I can optimize this process?

The database is a PostgreSQL, and I'm using the pgadmin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, don't convert dates to char, work with dates. To solve your task you need to group by by hour, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117796/how-do-i-group-by-by-hour-in-postgresql-with-a-time-field

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve, can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Or provide a little [SQL setup script](https://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler) with the table definitions and the sample data

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I altered the question text a bit, so hopefully now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youy can use GROUP BY and the `date_part` function to simplify things

```
SELECT date_part('month', create_time), count(*) 
FROM sing
WHERE date_part('year', create_time) = 2018
GROUP BY date_part('month', create_time)
```

and then for the day

```
SELECT date_part('day', create_time), count(*) 
FROM sing
WHERE date_part('year', create_time) = 2018
  AND date_part('month', create_time) = <month from previous query>
GROUP BY date_part('day', create_time)
```

and so on

Comment: You, sir, are brilliant! This was exactlty the sort of thing I was looking for! Now I can just continue to divide it into day, minutes etc. Thank you! Oh, just one more thing. If you want to do it by the year, you have to add that. So for example:               
SELECT date_part('day', create_time), count(*) 
FROM sing
where date_part('year', create_time) = '2018'
AND date_part('month', create_time) = '11'
GROUP BY date_part('day', create_time)

Comment: @MikeD Yes of course, I  forgot to include that. Actually for the year comparison it might be faster to use BETWEEN.

Answer (score 0):

For the year 2018 would be 1 query:

```
select count(*) from sing where date_part('year', create_time) = '2018'
```

So you can use better date_part then to_char I think

https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/date_part-function.php